# Symfony form and entity data, extra property show up in entity after form submission

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I am using Symfony3.

I have a Form, [SiteType](http://pastebin.com/YqTTr6EA) that is bound to entity [Site](http://pastebin.com/WveNZVQD). I am using doctrine annotations
to validate the form data. The error shows up in the form but error will never
disappear for field `sitemap_url` (please see the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY0Re.jpg).

Upon debugging, I found that
whatever I type in `sitemap_url` , it appears as extra property of the Site entity (please refer to screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY0Re.jpg)

The strange thing is that form element `exclude_regex_rule` is correctly mapped to entity property `excludeRegexRule`. And I was expecting the same for form field `sitemap_url` to map to entity property `sitemapUrl`.

snippet of code that handles the request [SiteController.php](http://pastebin.com/Xz0b8je1)

My `config.yml` has following entries for ORM.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        ...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

I am trying to understand what could have possibly gone wrong.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony Form Builder, child in `add` method must correspond with entity var.

In Your SiteType should be:

```
->add('sitemapUrl', TextType::class...
```

Comment: As Damonsson said. It may be a problem with your SiteType. Can you add that information. :)

Comment: @damonsson It did not work. If you see the `SiteType` there is another field `exclude_regex_rule` which maps correctly to entity field `excludeRegexRule` properties. I was expecting `sitemap_url` to be similar and would map to entity field `sitemapUrl`. Here `underscore` is used as `naming stragegy`. I have updated my question with this information. @eli